# Passing values between tabs in AJAX tabcontainer in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls

I have a ASP.net page with couple of tabpanels. When a user hits submit button when he is on the First tab I am showing the user the second tab control. Ontabindexchanged I am dynamically creating a usercontrol and passing some values to the control.

Now when the user is in the 2nd tab and if he navigates to the first tab, I need to pass some values to the first tab.

At the tabcontainer level how do I pass values between tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what your problem is, you need to maintain viewstate of your dynamically created controls, otherwise there is no problem to pass values between tabs. like..

tab1TextBox1.text=tab2Textbox2.text (Since your controls are in AJAX tab panel, no need to find control from tab panel)

For Maintaining viewstate of your dynamically created user control, you need to create your control in page_init() event.